# when using Pika BlockingConnection, Does basic_ack() has to be placed in callback function

Tags: rabbitmq, multiprocessing, pika

say I have made a connection to RabbitMQ like following:

```
connection = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters(
    'localhost', 5672, '/', credentials))
channel = connection.channel()
channel.queue_declare(queue=getting_from_this_queue)
channel.basic_consume(
    callback, queue=getting_from_this_queue, no_ack=False)
channel.basic_qos( prefetch_count = 3 )
```

to achieve better concurrency, I tried to place every job in an internal Queue, and created a while loop to asynchronously dispatch worker for every job retrieved from this internal Queue:

```
from Queue import Queue
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool as ThreadPool

task_queue = Queue(10)
pool = Pool(20)

def worker(ch, method, job):
    # ...some heavy lifting...
     if job_gets_done:         # some abstraction
        print "job success"
        ch.basic_ack(delivery_tag=method.delivery_tag)   # PROBLEM : this seems not working
     else:
        print "job failed"

def callback(ch, method, properties, job):
     task_queue.put((ch,method,dn))     # put job in internal queue, block if full.

@threaded
def async_process_jobs():              # loop to get job and start thread worker.
    while True:
         params = task_queue.get()
         pool.apply_async( worker, params )   # param = (ch,method, job)


async_process_jobs()
channel.start_consuming()
```

problem is, when the jobs are being processed, non-of them are sending acknowledgement properly (even if the execution flow really goes through it, i.e. prints "job success"). the queue size on rabbitmq stays the same, Why?

In a [somewhat official tutorial](http://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-two-python.html), the basic_ack() was placed inside callback(), but mine didn't. could this be the source of problem?

---

*Detailed Behaviour (may not be important): assume i have 10000 jobs in the queue, In the beginning, some 2000 message went into Unacked state, then all of them goes back to Ready state, even if my workers are still processing and printing "job succes"(acking).*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [FAQ of pika](http://pika.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html):

> Pika does not have any notion of threading in the code. If you want to
>   use Pika with threading, make sure you have a Pika connection per
>   thread, created in that thread. It is not safe to share one Pika
>   connection across threads.

Comment: btw there are many similar libraries for Python that actually does support threading; e.g. rabbitpy.

Comment: Yes but you can share the channel but it has to be done via connection method         conn.add_callback_threadsafe(cb) , 

Here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65516220/what-is-the-use-of-add-callback-threadsafe-method-in-pika

Answer (score 0):

i meet similar issue, i noticed that:
if the job done quickly, then the ack works
but if the job cost more time, then the ack not works, even it send out.