# What is the use of add_callback_threadsafe() method in pika?

Tags: rabbitmq, pika, rabbitmq-exchange, python-pika

From the description in the `pika` documentation, I can't quite get what `add_callback_threadsafe()` method does. It says, "Requests a call to the given function as soon as possible in the context of this connection’s thread". Specifically, which event does this callback get associated to? Since, `add_callback_threadsafe()` doesn't receive any "event" argument, how does `pika` know when to invoke that callback?

Also, in the official example, why do we even need to build the partial function and register the callback in the do_work() method? Could we not just call the `ack_message()` method after the `time.sleep()` is over?

Comment: Have you found the answer?

Answer (score 1):

The reason why the method exists:
[How to add multiprocessing to consumer with pika (RabbitMQ) in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55373867/how-to-add-multiprocessing-to-consumer-with-pika-rabbitmq-in-python)

If you use the same rabbit connection/channel with multiple threads/processes then you'll be prone to crashes. If you want to avoid that, you need to use that method.

> Could we not just call the ack_message() method after the
> time.sleep() is over?

No, you would be calling ack_message from a different thread than the main one, that's not thread safe and prone to crashes. You need to call ack_message from a thread-safe context, i.e., the add_callback_threadsafe().